# Matching the last best word using regex js

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a regex for matching the text within the brackets. For example the regex https://regex101.com/r/TvweUj/3

```
/\b(\w)[-'\w]* (?:[-",/\\*&'\w]* ){1,}\(\1[A-Z]{1,}\)/gi
```

matches **MIDI The USB Device Class Definition for MIDI Devices transmits Music Instrument Digital Interface (MIDI).** instead of only matching the last 4 words **Music Instrument Digital Interface**

How do I change my regex to match the recent matching instead from the **MIDI The USB Dev*******

Answer (score 1):

You might use 4 capturing groups with a positive lookahead asserting 4 backreferences to match the uppercase chars between the parenthesis:

```
\b([A-Z])\w+ ([A-Z])\w+ ([A-Z])\w+ ([A-Z])\w+(?= \(\1\2\3\4\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CrX0Gk/1)

Instead of using `\w` only, you could use the character classes that you use in the question like `[-",/\\*&'\w]*`

---

A more broad pattern could be repeating an uppercase char followed by 1+ word chars `\w+` (or use `\w*` to repeat 0+ word chars) and assert that what follows is only uppercase chars between parenthesis.

```
\b[A-Z]\w+(?: [A-Z]\w+)*(?= \([A-Z]+\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/04HmFB/1)

---

If the number of chars are variable that you want to match between the parenthesis and they should match with the number of words before, you could use 2 capturing groups and compare the amount of splitted words with the number of uppercase chars between the parenthesis.

```js
let pattern = /\b([A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*) \(([A-Z]+)\)/;
let compare = (ar1, ar2) =>
  ar1.length === ar2.length && ar1.every(
    (value, index) => value === ar2[index].charAt(0)
  );
[
  "transmits Music Instrument Digital Interface (MIDI).",
  "transmits Music Instrument Digital Interface (MADI).",
  "transmits Music Instrument Digital Interface (MID)."
].forEach(s => {
  let m = s.match(pattern);
  let res = compare(m[2].split(''), m[1].split(' ')) ? "Ok -> " : "Not ok -> ";
  console.log(res + s);
})
```

Comment: The first one works only if there are 4 characters inside(....) right ?

Comment: @rootkonda That is correct, and the 4 characters have to be the same same as those captured in the groups.

Comment: ok. I was looking for a way to generalize this for any character length inside( ). May be its  not feasible just using regex unless we combine this with some code ?

Comment: @rootkonda If you want to match the exact number of chars inside the parenthesis, you could for example get the match outside the parenthesis and split on a space and count the number of items to be equal to the number of chars inside it. Using for example 2 capturing groups https://regex101.com/r/yGIz8w/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird do you mind me asking why there a `?:` non capturing group

Comment: @Thefourthbird - If the text contains upper case letters before M then that also will get matched isn't it ? if the given string has "MIDI Devices Transmits Music Instrument Digital Interface (MIDI)", then the match will start from MIDI.

Comment: @rootkonda It will be matches, but that can be prevented by matching only lowercase chars a-z like `\b([A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*) \(([A-Z]+)\)`  https://regex101.com/r/3GgdPf/1

Comment: @Sven.hig There is a non capturing group `(?: [A-Z]\w+)*` to repeat what is inside as a whole.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you for your response, but forgive my ignorance, when i remove `?:` nothing changes and  i thought a non capturing group is to eliminate a group from showing in the match result am I wrong ? can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Sven.hig If you remove the non capturing group like this `\b[A-Z]\w+ [A-Z]\w+(?= \([A-Z]+\))` you will only match [Digital Interface](https://regex101.com/r/FKVcc9/1). If you turn the non capturing group into a capturing group `\b[A-Z]\w+( [A-Z]\w+)*(?= \([A-Z]+\))` you will capture the value of the last iteration which is [Interface](https://regex101.com/r/GjJet6/1). It will work but you don't need the capturing group at all for the full match.

Comment: I got it and thank you very much for your time, I will highly appreciate it if you can recommend any good resources to read more about this

Comment: @Sven.hig No problem, these pages are for example a good read about groups: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#noncap and https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions